# Unable to fix broken dipendencies

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

I recently updated to ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and every time I try to install a package I get the following in the terminal:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libasn1-8-heimdal libffi7 libgssapi3-heimdal libhcrypto4-heimdal
  libheimbase1-heimdal libheimntlm0-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal libicu66
  libkrb5-26-heimdal libldap-2.4-2 libllvm10 libroken18-heimdal
  libwind0-heimdal linux-headers-5.15.0-43 linux-headers-5.15.0-43-generic
  linux-image-5.15.0-43-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-43-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-43-generic
  linux-modules-nvidia-515-5.15.0-43-generic
  linux-objects-nvidia-515-5.15.0-43-generic
  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-43-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
9 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/173 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libedata-cal-2.0-1:amd64:
 libedata-cal-2.0-1:amd64 depends on libecal-2.0-1 (>= 3.39.3); however:
  Package libecal-2.0-1:amd64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libedata-cal-2.0-1:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up er
ror from a previous failure.
                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of e
volution-data-server:
 evolution-data-server depends on libecal-2.0-1 (>= 3.39.2); however:
  Package libecal-2.0-1:amd64 is not installed.
 evolution-data-server depends on libedata-cal-2.0-1 (>= 3.26.2); however:
  Package libedata-cal-2.0-1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package evolution-data-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libedataserverui-1.2-3:amd64:
 libedataserverui-1.2-3:amd64 depends on libecal-2.0-1 (>= 3.33.4); however:
  Package libecal-2.0-1:amd64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libedataserverui-1.2-3:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-calendar:
 gnome-calendar depends on libecal-2.0-1 (>= 3.33.4); however:
  Package libecal-2.0-1:amd64 is not installed.
 gnome-calendar depends oNo apport report written because the error message indi
cates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                     No apport report written be
cause the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure
.
 No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                     No apport r
eport written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                         No apport report writte
n because MaxReports has already been reached
                                             n libedataserverui-1.2-3 (>= 3.17.1
); however:
  Package libedataserverui-1.2-3:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-calendar (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-shell:
 gnome-shell depends on evolution-data-server (>= 3.33.1); however:
  Package evolution-data-server is not configured yet.
 gnome-shell depends on libecal-2.0-1 (>= 3.33.4); however:
  Package libecal-2.0-1:amd64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-shell (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-session:
 ubuntu-session depends on gnome-shell (>= 3.37.91); however:
  Package gnome-shell is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-session (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gdm3:
 gdm3 No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                          No app
ort report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                              depends on gnome-s
hell (>= 3.37.90); however:
  Package gnome-shell is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gdm3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-todo:
 gnome-todo depends on libecal-2.0-1 (>= 3.33.4); however:
  Package libecal-2.0-1:amd64 is not installed.
 gnome-todo depends on libedataserverui-1.2-3 (>= 3.33.4); however:
  Package libedataserverui-1.2-3:amd64 is not configured yet.
 gnome-todo depends on evolution-data-server (>= 3.17.1); however:
  Package evolution-data-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-todo (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libedata-cal-2.0-1:amd64
 evolution-data-server
 libedataserverui-1.2-3:amd64
 gnome-calendar
 gnome-shell
 ubuntu-session
 gdm3
 gnome-todo
```

I tried removing the packages manually but that throws yet another error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 evolution-data-server : Depends: libecal-2.0-1 (>= 3.39.2) but it is not going to be installed
 gnome-calendar : Depends: libecal-2.0-1 (>= 3.33.4) but it is not going to be installed
 gnome-shell : Depends: libecal-2.0-1 (>= 3.33.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libedata-cal-2.0-1 : Depends: libecal-2.0-1 (>= 3.39.3) but it is not going to be installed
 libedataserverui-1.2-3 : Depends: libecal-2.0-1 (>= 3.33.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Does anyone know how I can fix the problem?

Comment: you can use `dpkg --force-depends -r packagename` to remove a package and ignore the dependencies.  that is good if you plan on installing those packages later.  of course, you should be very careful using the override as it can break your session if you remove something important or in use.

Comment: It all revolves about libecal-2.0-1:amd64 not installed. Did you try to install it using --fix-broken? `apt-get install --fix-broken libecal-2.0-1:amd64`. Of course if you know you did something strange, like switching distribution version or adding repositories that could conflict, you should tell it.